# passing on parameter from html to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to pass a parameter from HTML to jQuery, however I get only 1 type of answer even though I use a for loop just as below in my php file:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
  echo "<button ><a class='href' data-id='$x'>Text</a></button>";
}
```

I retrieve it like this:

```
$y = $('.href').attr('data-id');
```

Is there something I'm not doing right?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using concatenation for that string? ie: data-id='" . $x . "'>.......?

Comment: @remixdesign Not necessary for PHP.

Comment: PHP will parse variables within double quotes, @remixdesign

Comment: ok cool - wanted to make sure - im so used to it in javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
$(".href").each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

**Explanation**

Your code runs and works, just not the way you think it works.

Let's assume that `$length` is equal to `2` (doesn't really matter):

```
$length = 2;
for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++)
{
    echo "<button ><a class='href' data-id='$x'>Text</a></button>";
}
```

It will generate two buttons, one with id `0` and one with id `1`:

```
<button ><a class='href' data-id='0'>Text</a></button>
<button ><a class='href' data-id='1'>Text</a></button>
```

You're trying to fetch the value like this:

```
$y = $('.href').attr('data-id');
```

And it does, however, it [only fetches the data-id matching the first element which has class 'href'](http://jsfiddle.net/1gtsvL8d/1/), as explained in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

If you wish to get the `id` of the currently clicked button then you can do it like this:

```
$('.href').on("click", function()
{
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

(Listening to click events on elements with class `href`)

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/baq2dkj1/)

If you wish to get all available ids then you can go through each and every one of them and get the ids:

```
<p id="output"></p>
$(".href").each(function()
{
    var currentId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#output").append("Button id: " + currentId + "<br />");
});
```

(Parsing through each instance of the element which has the class `href`)

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgjh89Lc/)

Comment: Tried your suggestion on getting the id of the currently clicked button and it worked, thanx for all the answers everyone they really helped :)

Answer (score 5):

From http://api.jquery.com/attr/:

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first** element in the set

(emphasis added)

That is, even though `$('.href')` matches `$length` elements, it only gives you `0`.

Also from the docs,

> To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's `.each()` or `.map()` method.

(everyone else is posting code samples, so ...)

```
var y = $('.href').map(function (index, element) {
    return $(element).attr('data-id');
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only going to give you the first id, not an array of IDs.  You'll need to do an each to get more than one ID.

```
y = [];
$('.href').each(function() {
  y.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
alert(y);
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r863e7v/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to retrieve the data values. Also use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`:

```
$('.href').each(function(i,a) {
    var y = $(a).data('id') 
    // use y
    console.log( y );
});
```